# Java: remove one object in a list which is in a list

Tags: java, filter, java-stream

Hi I have a list of of users who can have several questions. Each questions can have several answers. I want to filter out the incorrect ones. 
I have tried the code below, but the filter is not working. I want to know why

```
Users.stream().forEach(user ->
            user.getAnswers().stream().forEach(answer ->
                    answer.getReplies().stream().filter(reply ->
                            !reply.getValue().equals("INCORRECT")).collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

Many thanks

Comment: Well you create a new list, but you do nothing with it.

Comment: "*not working*" is not helpful at all. Have you inspected what your code actually does with a debugger?

Comment: What object are you trying to remove? `User`, or `Question` or `Reply`?

Comment: Thank for your responses : 
I am trying to return the whole users objects.. with the incorrect replies filtered

Comment: Note that you should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variable names start with lowercase (i.e. `Users` should be `users`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to collect only replies, try this:

```
List<Reply> correctReplies = Users.stream()
    .flatMap(user -> user.getAnswers().stream())
    .flatMap(answer -> answer.getReplies().stream())
    .filter(reply -> !reply.getValue().equals("INCORRECT"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

To get only user with any correct answer:

```
List<User> usersWithCorrectReplies = Users.stream()
    .filter(user -> user.getAnswers().stream()
            .flatMap(answer -> answer.getReplies().stream())
            .anyMatch(reply -> !reply.getValue().equals("INCORRECT"))
    )
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you want to filter only correct replies from a user, you have to change your class, because this is responsibility of that object:

```
class User {
    List<Answer> getAnswers() { ... }

    List<Reply> correctReplies() {
        return getAnswers().stream()
                .flatMap(answer -> answer.getReplies().stream())
                .filter(reply -> !reply.getValue().equals("INCORRECT"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    boolean hasCorrectReplies() {
        return getAnswers().stream()
                .flatMap(answer -> answer.getReplies().stream())
                .anyMatch(reply -> !reply.getValue().equals("INCORRECT"));
    }
}
```

Then you can use it:

```
List<User> usersWithCorrectReplies2 = Users.stream()
    .filter(User::hasCorrectReplies)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

usersWithCorrectReplies2.forEach(user -> user.correctReplies()
    .forEach(System.out::println));
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer.. I wanted to return the whole users objects with the incorrect replies filtered out

Comment: I don't think that is possible, it would need to change the implementation of `getReplies` method. Or do you mean, you want only users, which have some correct answers?

Comment: No, I really want to filter out the incorrect responses.
I was thinking about maybe doing it through the getters... I don't know if that is a good practice..